# Best way to Bulk-remove records? Can I chain multiple remove bulk operations in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection where some documents happen to have different types for the same property. I want to remove the documents that are incorrect based on that criteria. So I think I can do this:

```js
var db = db.getSiblingDB('db'),
   coll = db.getCollection("coll"),
    bulk = coll.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    /* some stuff in between here and there */
bulk.find(
    { 
        "doc.prop1": { $exists: true } 
    }
).remove();

bulk.find(
    { 
        "doc.prop2":{ 
            $exists: true,
            $isArray: true,
            $elemMatch: { 
                "elem": { $type: "object" }
            } 
        }
).remove();

bulk.execute();
```

What is best way do remove records according to multiple queries/filters in a single bulk operation?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where `_id` values were either String or ObjectId (legacy db...) Using the script below, all were converted to ObjectId. Load it using [mongo load](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/load/).

```
// find the length of collection (collection name is "documents")

var total = db.documents.find().length();
print("found " + total + " documents"); 

// Now find all the items that need to be updated
var documentCursor = db.documents.find().limit(total);

var toBeDeleted = [];

documentCursor.forEach(function(doc) {
    print("Starting with item # " + total);
    var oldId = doc._id; // store old id
    print(" --> oldId : ", oldId);

    try {
        doc._id = new ObjectId();
        db.documents.insert(doc);
        print("new id: ", doc._id);
        toBeDeleted.push(oldId);
        total = total - 1;
    } catch (e) {
        print("failed to insert: ", e);
    }
});

// Afterwards delete the old items
try {
    db.documents.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: toBeDeleted } });
} catch (e) {
    print("Failed to delete: ", e);
}
```

The deletion was necessary because `_id` can't be updated. For other properties I would do something similar but then use [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/)

---

> Recent backup is a no brainer. What I really liked was that I could easily reload that specific collection and start over. 
>   I use [mlab](https://mlab.com) and their docs after login quickly helped me to restore the collection.